# How use methods from RinSim library when error is "is not public in package"?

Tags: rinsim

When I try to create for example a CommDeviceBuilder for my own class I get this error telling me it's not a public method. How am I supposed to make a builder like this then?

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to instantiate instances of `CommDeviceBuilder` yourself. You can obtain an instance by letting your class (e.g. your agent) implement the [CommUser](https://github.com/rinde/RinSim/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/github/rinde/rinsim/core/model/comm/CommUser.java) interface.

[RandomBroadcastAgent](https://github.com/rinde/RinSim/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/github/rinde/rinsim/examples/comm/RandomBroadcastAgent.java) is an example implementation of this mechanism (also see [CommExample](https://github.com/rinde/RinSim/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/github/rinde/rinsim/examples/comm/CommExample.java)).